# Forvalues loop in R: how to loop through data frames in R with name stubs and an identifying (consecutive) number

Tags: r, loops, foreach

I would like to loop through data frames in R (each with the same name stub and a different identifying number/index at the end of the name) to create new dataframes with different name stubs and the same identifying number as the data frame it was created from.

Here is a link to the data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14cGmcjGkYfr5X-ZE08uA71-X_wQiw_TY?usp=sharing

Below is the code for I would like, where [i] would be replaced by the consecutive ID number 1 through 204.  Is there an elegant way to do this?

```
for (i in 1:204) {
ref[i] <- read.dta("F:/ref[i]pde.dta")
distref[i] <-osrmTable(loc=ref[i][1:nrow(ref[i]), c("pde","lon","lat")])
trips[i] <-osrmTable(loc=ref[i])
}
```

Comment: I don't think the Stata tag helps here. Your question is about R and benefits from focus on what you want to know. I think you want to loop over filenames here, and if that is the essence then rewriting the question in terms of text or string manipulation might help. (I am not in any sense whatsoever hostile to Stata, or R for that matter, but I am not a routine R user.)

Comment: Generally the best way to loop through a collection of related objects is to store them in a list and then act on the individual list items with an apply function, e.g `lapply`.  Moreover a object index is implicitly applied to each member of the list by its index number in the list.  e.g., `my_list[[1]]` would be the 1st df in your list, `my_list[[5]]` would be the 5th df in your list, etc.

Comment: What are your file name pattern: `ref1pde.dta`, `ref2pde.dta`, etc.? How are *ref*, *distref*, and *trips* originally assigned? Also, `length` of data frame is equal to number of columns (not rows).

Comment: Thank you! the name patterns are consecutive numbers from 1 through 204. So for the number of rows for each DF, the correct code might be [1:nrows[ref[i]).  And the mylist function can be used both for naming new objects and in the functions? Can you recommend a relevant example ( I have searched many entries for something like this!) Thank you!